# In PHP, how to save words separated by space and lines and put words in array

Tags: php, arrays, string, tokenize

I need your help. I have a variable name **$thetextstring** which contain 9 words separated with LINE BREAKS and SPACES which I fetched from an html form.

```
$thetextstring = "alpha bravo charlie
delta echo
foxtrot
golf hotel india" ;
```

How can I tokenize the php string $thetextstring to remove the lines and spaces and put the 9 words inside an array like this

```
$thetextarray[0] = "alpha";
$thetextarray[1] = "bravo";
$thetextarray[2] = "charlie";
$thetextarray[3] = "delta";
$thetextarray[4] = "echo";
$thetextarray[5] = "foxtrot";
$thetextarray[6] = "golf";
$thetextarray[7] = "hotel";
$thetextarray[8] = "india";
```

I need the php code to handle this. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: use explode function for this... take look of it http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Use 'explode()' php function ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want, I removed all additional new line and space.

```
$thetextstring = "alpha bravo charlie
delta echo
foxtrot
golf hotel india" ;
$thetextstring = preg_replace("#[\s]+#", " ", $thetextstring);
$words = explode(" ", $thetextstring);
print_r($words);

(
    [0] => alpha
    [1] => bravo
    [2] => charlie
    [3] => delta
    [4] => echo
    [5] => foxtrot
    [6] => golf
    [7] => hotel
    [8] => india
)
```

Answer (score 5):

use simple [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

```
$str="new sample string";
$str=preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $str);
$arr=explode(" ",$str);
print_r($arr);
```

output :

```
Array ( [0] => new [1] => sample [2] => string )
```

Comment: this is not correct answer, did you tested and see what's the output?

Comment: No, you need to remove extra white space and new lines before

Comment: i ran the code on phpfiddle.org and this was the output          Array ( [0] => new [1] => sam ple  )

Comment: @mostafakhansa are you sure ?

Answer (score 0):

See function `multiexplode` in comments of PHP `explode()` documentation for using explode with more than one delimiter.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#111307

Answer (score 0):

```
$thetextstring = "alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india" ; 

$c=  explode(" ", $thetextstring);
print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$thetextstring = "alpha bravo charlie
delta echo
foxtrot
golf hotel india" ;

$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $thetextstring));

$result =  explode(" ", $thetextstring);

print_r( $result );
```

First you should remove all the new line from given string so it will be clear that you have only one line of string with no new line characters / breaks.

Then Explode function will create an array from given string separated by SPACE.

last You can print result to see the each word as a single entity in array.